# Temporary tables that last through browser session

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my web application, I store some data on the local storage of browsers. This data forms a part of the following SQL. Users may request the SQL many times in a session.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE id NOT IN (...local storage data) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

To avoid posting data from local storage each time the request is made, can I create a temporary table to store the data instead, that can last until the user leaves my site?

Comment: Please tell us what `...local storage data` represents.  Is it a list of values?  A SQL fragment?  Something else?

Comment: Server mysql or WebSQL?

Comment: It's a list of values. MySQL DB as stated in the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me to store data is much easier using this:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['variable'] = "data";
?>
```

to save it simply by post method with some additional js code make it realtime.

using back the "$_SESSION" code to insert it into ***database or csv file.***

**Yes. Its required another php page to perform this. Because php cannot be update with realtime data in a page. Its done and never do another task once the page is completely 100% loaded**